# Choosing user with Pig Mapreduce mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I simply do `pig -fs 192.168.1.13:8020 -jt 192.168.1.13:8021`, I find myself in the `user/clientname` folder, which doesn't exist. On top of that, I can't read any files.

Is there any way to use the mapreduce mode like this : 
`pig -fs 192.168.1.13:8020 -jt 192.168.1.13:8021 -username fxm -pwd somepwd` ?